# 301 Redirecting every link based off one link

Tags: wordpress, redirect

So I'm going to try and not make this sound confusing!

Basically I've got a WordPress website and they have nearly 800 URLs they want to redirect, now I really don't have the time to spend hours redirecting every individual link...

Most of the links are like https://url/journal/{anotherlink}

I was wondering if there was a way to 301 redirect everything on /journal (including extra links off that) to another page on the site so I only have to do 1 redirect rather than 700 individual ones...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond /journal/$ [NC]
RewriteRule https;//newurl.com/category/$1 [L,R=301]
```